# Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, gulp

Собираю себе проект и вот ошибку получаю, не пойму в чём проблема.

Вот текст ошибки:

```
**Error: spawn EACCES
at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)**
```

Сам конфиг `gulp`

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
watch = require('gulp-watch'),
prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
rimraf = require('rimraf'),
//
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
rjs = require('gulp-requirejs'),
//
browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
reload = browserSync.reload;

var path = {
build: {
    html: 'build/',
    js: 'build/js/',
    css: 'build/css/',
    img: 'build/img/',
    fonts: 'build/fonts/'
},
src: {
    html: 'src/*.html',
    js: 'src/js/main.js',
    style: 'src/style/style.scss',
    img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
    fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
},
watch: {
    html: 'src/**/*.html',
    js: 'src/js/**/*.js',
    style: 'src/style/**/*.scss',
    img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
    fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
},
clean: './build'
};

var config = {
server: {
    baseDir: "./build"
},
tunnel: true,
host: 'localhost',
port: 8095,
logPrefix: "Frontend"
};

gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    browserSync(config);
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('html:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    rjs({
            name:'main',
            baseUrl:'./src/js/',
            out:'main.js',
            paths:{
                // 'jquery':'../libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
                // 'backbone':'../libs/backbone/backbone.min',
                // 'underscore':'../libs/underscore/underscore.min',
                // 'handlebars':'../libs/handlebars/handlebars.amd.min'
            }
    })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        // .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('style:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.style)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['src/style/'],
            outputStyle: 'compressed',
            sourceMap: true,
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(prefixer())
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('image:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.img)
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()],
            interlaced: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('fonts:build', function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts))
});

gulp.task('build', [
    'html:build',
    'js:build',
    'style:build',
    'fonts:build',
    'image:build'
]);


gulp.task('watch', function(){
    watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('html:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.style], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('style:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.js], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('js:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.img], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('image:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.fonts], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('fonts:build');
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

Сори почему-то индексация не сохраняется, тэг `pre` прерывается, пришлось закинуть просто так(

```
**Я сижу с ubuntu 14.04,
node v0.10.25,
gulp CLI version 3.8.11  Local version 3.8.11,
npm 1.3.10**
```

Comment: похоже, что проблемы с правами на файлы

Comment: Да, типо того, я искал в интернете решение,но не нашёл которое мне бы помогло...